# How do I include a Django project's README.md in a template?

Tags: python, django, github, django-templates

I want to add the text of the readme to a custom index template in admin. So I have the following relevant paths in the project:

./README.md
./impact_api/templates/admin/index.html

And in the project settings I have

```
TEMPLATES = [
  {
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
    ...}]
```

So in the index.html file I want to do something like this:

```
{% include "../../README.md" %}
```

But that raises an error:

`TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/ The relative path '"../../README.md"' points outside the file hierarchy that template 'admin/index.html' is in.`

The only things I can think of are a) to move the README into the body, which I'm not sure I can do without losing the display on Github and seems like a bad idea even if I can, or to change the templates lookup path to the entire project, which also seems like a terrible idea. Is there a more sensible option?

Comment: How about loading the README file in your view and passing it via context to your index template?

Comment: That's a much better idea... Thanks!